# Wordpress Menu Dropdown

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu

Ok so i have looked everywhere and can not find anything. I know i might need some jquery or something. I have tried asking over at wordpress.org but that was a waste of time as i have had no replies for 2-3 days so now i will ask here.

1. My goal is to have a main menu that shows the active page it is on and have a drop down for other menu items. I have that figured out.
2. My next thing is to have the child menu of a parent shown when parent or child is active. Kind of have the figured out. The child menu displays but by css when parent is active.
3. The next this when parent two is active and/or child of parent two is active i would like it to go back to normal style if i hover over any other menu item weather is has a child menu or not. If it has a child menu then i want it shown in place instead of parent two.

A somewhat good example of what i am trying to achieve but they dont use the nav menu on any other page is [MSN](http://www.msn.com) there main nav (NEWS, Entrainment, etc.) is what i am looking for but want the parent and/or child menu shown if active but disappear when hovering over other menu items with or without child menu's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to some extent but have posted another question regarding my other issues if you think you can help then please visit this  but for others here was my solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   $("see #1 below ").hover(function(){     
       $('see #2 below ').addClass(" see #3 below ");    
   },     
   function(){    
       $(' copy #2 ').removeClass("copy #3 ");     
    });
});
```

1. Put the id or class you want the script to be activated by here
2. Put the id or class you want the script to add a class to here
3. Put the class you want the script to add to the class or id listed for #2

you can add multiple id's or classes by inserting a comma (see example below)
here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   $("#navbar li:hover, #navbar li.sfhover").hover(function(){     
       $('#navbar .current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').addClass("non-ahover");    
   },     
   function(){    
       $('#navbar li.current-menu-parent, #navbar li.current-menu-item').removeClass("non-ahover");     
    });
});
```